# Connection from Java Application and Stored Procedure MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters

I have the stored procedure in SQL Sever and it has a few parameter. I would like to give the value of parameter from the combo box (in java application). I've read this code (look at below)

```
public static void executeSprocInParams(Connection con) {
   try {
      PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("{call dbo.uspGetEmployeeManagers(?)}");
      pstmt.setInt(1, 50);
      ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

      while (rs.next()) {
         System.out.println("EMPLOYEE:");
         System.out.println(rs.getString("LastName") + ", " + rs.getString("FirstName"));
         System.out.println("MANAGER:");
         System.out.println(rs.getString("ManagerLastName") + ", " + rs.getString("ManagerFirstName"));
         System.out.println();
      }
      rs.close();
      pstmt.close();
   }

   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But i didn't get the meaning. Is there any tutorial that give me some example just like in my case? Thanks for any reply

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("{call dbo.uspGetEmployeeManagers(?)}");
  pstmt.setInt(1, 50);
  ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

1) Line 1 creates a prepare statement object with your Stored Procedure. The ? is the placeholder for the input parameter to the Stored Procs
2) Line 2 sets the input param to the stored proc
3) executeQuery executes the stored proc by providing the input and get the output as a resultset.

```
while (rs.next()) {
     System.out.println("EMPLOYEE:");
     System.out.println(rs.getString("LastName") + ", " + rs.getString("FirstName"));
     System.out.println("MANAGER:");
     System.out.println(rs.getString("ManagerLastName") + ", " + rs.getString("ManagerFirstName"));
     System.out.println();
  }
  rs.close();
  pstmt.close();
```

Above lines iterate over the result set and print each record

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void executeSprocInParams(Connection con) {
   try {
      PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("{call dbo.uspGetEmployeeManagers(?)}");//Creating a prepared statement with the string to execute your procedure.
      pstmt.setInt(1, 50);//This is to set the parameter to the place holder '?'
      ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();//This is to execute your procedure and put the result into a table like set

  while (rs.next()) {//To check if there are any values in the set, if so the print those values
     System.out.println("EMPLOYEE:");
     System.out.println(rs.getString("LastName") + ", " + rs.getString("FirstName"));
     System.out.println("MANAGER:");
     System.out.println(rs.getString("ManagerLastName") + ", " + rs.getString("ManagerFirstName"));
     System.out.println();
  }
  rs.close();//close the set
  pstmt.close();//close the statement
   }

   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```